# Two+ node elasticsearch cluster - mirroring?

Tags: elasticsearch

We wish to place an elasticsearch cluster on top of a kubernetes cluster (currently with 2 nodes, but we have plans to increase this).

Is it possible to configure elasticsearch in such a way that every node in the cluster contains identical data? so that if a node is lost then the remaining nodes in the cluster can continue to function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to set the number of [replicas](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/replica-shards.html) equal to the number of nodes minus one.

Comment: thanks for the information. We set the ES option "index.number_of_replicas:" in our config file.  To update the existing running indices we used a curl XPUT command as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#indices-update-settings)

Comment: This is the command ```curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/<INDEX_NAME>/_settings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "number_of_replicas": 1 }'```